# vmware bridged mode and NAT is not connecting

Tags: networking, vmware

I've tried every adapter settings to be able connect internet through VM, but VM seems it can't connect in bridged mode and also NAT mode.

I tried to run couple of commands such as

```
service networking down
service networking start
ifconfig eth0 down
ifconfig eth0 up
```

None of them seems working.

Please tell me what I should do

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You might delete or disable one of VMware services. You can open services.msc via Run to search vmware services.

- Please go **Edit** > **Virtual Network Editor** on your VMware
- You need to get administrator previleges to Restore Defaults first
  click on **Change Settings** button.
- Click on Restore Defaults and wait for it finish